# How to rewrite $Y = A + (XA-AX)$ as a valid SDP constraint?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I want to write a SDP formulation with **variables $X$ and $Y$.**

Suppose I have the following constraint:

$$Y = A + (XA-AX)$$

where the constant matrix $A\succeq 0$.

I know a valid equality constraint in SDP should be an affine. How to rewrite the above equality constraint as an affine constraint?

Comment: This is already an affine constraint, I would say.

Comment: @littleO Just a kindly ask that I remember it should look like the form $\operatorname{tr}(A_iX) = b_i$?  I am still not very good at this part.

Comment: Are you in explicit need of this low-level form? In practice, you most often use modelling tools where this is taken care of automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following linear matrix equation in $\mathrm X, \mathrm Y \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$

$$\rm A X - X A + Y = A$$

Vectorizing, we obtain the following linear system of $n^2$ equations in $2 n^2$ unknowns

$$\left( \mathrm I_n \otimes \mathrm A - \mathrm A^{\top} \otimes \mathrm I_n \right) \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) + \mbox{vec} (\mathrm Y) = \mbox{vec} (\mathrm A)$$

where each equation can be written in the form

$$\langle \mathrm M_i, \mathrm X \rangle + \langle \mathrm N_i, \mathrm Y \rangle = b_i$$

where

- $\mathrm M_i$ is the un-vectorization of the $i$-th row of $\mathrm I_n \otimes \mathrm A - \mathrm A^{\top} \otimes \mathrm I_n$
- $\mathrm N_i$ is the un-vectorization of the $i$-th row of $\mathrm I_{n^2}$.

Comment: Could you please add that what $M_i$ and $N_i$ are explicitly?